# Calling method from different class using particular guidelines

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I need to call a method from a different class, and I'm having trouble with this. Difficult to grasp. I need to display the name of the highest bidder, note println with bid value in the **if** part.

**Guidelines:**
I need to use the getName method of the Person class. I will first need to get an object of the Person class. Do that by using the highestBid object and calling the getBidder method; it returns a Person object. Use that object to call the getName() method.

Here is my code:

```
public void close(int lotNumber, String description)
{
     for(Lot lot : lots) 
     {
         System.out.println(lotNumber + description); //print lot number and description.
         Bid highestBid = lot.getHighestBid(); //get the highest bid for the lot.
         if (highestBid != null) 
         {
             System.out.println(bidder + highestBid.getValue()); //print bidder and highest bid value
            }     
         else
         {
             System.out.println("Not sold"); //if not sold print "Not sold"
            }
        }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is wrong with your code? where does it fail? What exactly is your question?

Comment: You said getBidder() returns a Person object yet Bid highestBid = getBidder(); ? I'm confused

Comment: I need to call the getName method of class Person, within the if statement here. I need to use the guidelines listed above in order to do it too.

Comment: sorry the Bid highestBid = getBidder part was  me trying to figure this out. I've removed it.

Comment: I can't find variable bidder either. bidder is a method within Person class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming getName() returns a String:

```
public void close(int lotNumber, String description)
{
 for(Lot lot : lots) 
 {
     System.out.println(lotNumber + description); //print lot number and description.
     Bid highestBid = lot.getHighestBid(); //get the highest bid for the lot.
     if (highestBid != null) 
     {
         String name = highestBid.getBidder().getName();
         System.out.println(name + " " + highestBid.getValue()); //print bidder and highest bid value
        }     
     else
     {
         System.out.println("Not sold"); //if not sold print "Not sold"
        }
    }
}
```